# Code changes on Export?

Tags: android, xml

Whenever I export my java project my code changes from this:

```
...
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"  >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.candybird.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

to this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.candybird.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Which makes the orientation lock not work when its on my phone, nor does the title bar get removed???

Comment: Do you mean when you make the APK of your app then it does this??. If so this is quite weird and no possible afaik

Comment: Yes whenever I export to .APK

Comment: Are you using the Android Studio?